# Pass arbitrary parameters to dial (client) call

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

Use Case:

We have a simple menu built in twiml which asks the language of the user (one of 3 languages possible).

Then we redirect them via Dial and Client to one of our customer support people (most customer support people speak at least 2 languages)

The client is a simple page we have built (with integration in our CRM) based on the twilio client javascript.

Now we want to pass the language so we can display the chosen lannguage to the customer success manager.

I know we have the parameters on the incoming call (https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/connection#parameters) but this does not seem to allow us to pass arbitrary parameters. Also in the dial / client twiml verb we see no method to pass extra data.

Is there a possibility to achieve the same behaviour?

Comment: Would it be possible at the point that you get the language response from the user to set that as a field in your CRM? Then, when the client gets an incoming call and looks up the caller in the CRM it will be available there?

Comment: Hi, tthat would be a possibility, but at this point we want to minimize the interactions with any system (we are using twilio functions)
But we certainly will consider that a possibility

Comment: You could use the [`url` attribute of `<Client>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/client#attributes-url) which can be used to read a message to the agent before they answer the call?